# Creating an Automator app

Tags: automator

I would like to have a clickable app that will open a terminal window, run the script:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

and then close the terminal app. (and another to turn off the show all, same script with No at end). Automator seems to have a lot of potential, with not enough documentation that's easily found.

Comment: To those voting to close - How is this OT when this is not? - [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126660/alfred-how-to-get-alfred-to-run-a-terminal-command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126660/alfred-how-to-get-alfred-to-run-a-terminal-command)

Comment: Why open in terminal at all. Why not just use the Automator action “run shell script”

Comment: Matt - I don't know. Perhaps my question should have been "I have a need to frequently turn on/off the visibility of hidden files, what is the best way to simplify this process?"

Comment: What version of OS X/macOS are you running? IIRC, Since Sierra all you have to do is press Space+Command+. to toggle hidden files.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Please ask this on meta it is a good question and I would like to see the answer as I believe both should be closed.

Comment: @user3439894 - I’m on Yosemite. Too many applications that won’t make the jump to next OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not enough documentation

Umm...[Welcome to Automator - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/automator/welcome/mac)

[This is also a great link](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Welcome+to+Automator+-+Apple+Support)

---

### There is so many different ways of doing what you want.

**Option A**: Shell Script (Does in background)

**Option B**: Open Terminal Window

---

### A

**Option 1**: Pure AppleScript (Using `/Applications/Utilities/Script Editor.app`)

`do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES"`

**Option 2**: Pure Automator

[image]

**Option 3**: Automator + AppleScript

[image]

---

### B

**Option 1**: Pure AppleScript

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES"
end tell
```

**Option 2:** Automator + AppleScript

(A3 with the in B1)

---

For the toggle hears the AppleScript Code to be used in any option of your choosing:

```
set a to (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles")
if a is "YES" then
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO"
else
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES"
end if
```

---

### Export Options

**Script Editor**:

File>Export

- File Format: Application

**Automator**:

Choose Application when creating a new document

[image]

Comment: Much thanks! It was worth the DV to get such a great answer. Yes, I looked at the support site, and it wasn't quite sinking in.

Answer (score 2):

I think using AppleScript would be a reasonable solution.

This code will do as you have requested.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES"
    quit
end tell
```

Clearly, all you would need to change is the `YES` to a `NO` to have it turn it off instead.

As for saving it as a clickable app, you could either simply paste, compile and export as an "Application" to do this straight from the AppleScript Editor itself.

However, if you are dead set on using Automator, open automator, create new document, select Application then click "choose".
Next, search for "Run AppleScript", drag it into the main box. Now simply paste the AppleScript code from above where it indicates then press save. That's it! You can then repeat this process again and exchange `YES` for `NO` to get the two apps you need.

Hope that helped, please refer to [Welcome to Automator](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/automator/welcome/mac) for future reference.

Comment: I have just seen that @JBis has responded with a more detailed version of what I have suggested. Kind regards!